# Spring 3.0.6 with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

My application is build on Java 8, Spring 3.0.6 and running on Tomcat 7.

It all works fine.

However, when I update the Tomcat version to 8 I get the below.

Does anyone know if Spring 3 has any issues running on Tomcat 8?

```
    [2016-05-25 11:21:40,307][INFO] - ContextLoader.log: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[2016-05-25 11:21:41,072][ERROR] - ContextLoader.log: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:280) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Do some spring jars are in lib folder your tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

`EnvironmentCapable` class is available from spring 3.1 onward.

Please run `mvn:dependency tree` command to correctly check for all dependencies.

Comment: Its not a maven project. Is there any other way to find out? Also does that mean I'll have to upgrade to spring 3.1. I am currently on 3.0.6

Comment: Yes you can upgrade it to spring 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat8 is compatible with Spring 3.1 or later. You switch to Spring3.1, It will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8 requires 'ConfigurableEnvironment' class on startup. This class is present in spring-core 3.1.0 jar and onwards. Hence, you need to upgrade your spring version.